# If a batsman is bowled off a free hit, can he still score any runs?

Tags: cricket

I want to know about a cricket match result.

Last ball was no ball so next ball will be a free hit.

For no ball  SCORE is LEVEL. Now the batting side need 1 run from 1 ball.
Bowler finishes his ball by hitting the leg stumps and both batsman on the crease go for a run and complete 1 run without getting out.

In this case the Batsman will be not out because it was a free hit.

But the ball hit the leg stump and then batsman completed 1 run.

It's a legal ball but also a free hit.

I think this match result will be tie because last ball hit the leg stump so no chance to run.

Is it? Am I right?

Who will win?
Bowling side?
Batting side?
Or match tie?

Answer (score 8):

On a free hit, the batsman is not out even if the ball hits the stumps. Therefore, the ball is not dead, and the batsmen can run although the striker has been bowled. The batting side would then win, since they have completed the one run they need to overhaul the fielding side's target.

Comment: Yes, unless a fielder manages to pick up the ball and remove a bail (or stump if both bails are already removed) before they complete the run, then it is a tie

Comment: @user1672694 it is unnecessary to state the situation of a run out. There can be other situations as well like obstructing the field.

Comment: @hims056 if stating a run out is unnecessary then so is stating obstructing the field

Comment: @user: I am not stating the law of obstructing the field. I am just giving an example same as run out. No offence. :)

Comment: Would be interested if it still applies if he plays a shot or not. Cause under a normal situation if a bye is run and no shot is attempted then it will be considered a no run.

Comment: @aqwert Are you thinking of disallowed leg byes ([Law 26.3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-26-bye-and-leg-bye/))? Byes can be scored even when the batsman does not play a shot.

Comment: @Spinner,.. yes sorry meant that no shot played and they run, which you are correct is off the body

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a little clarification based on the wording of the question... The batsman himself won't be able to score any runs unless the ball touches either the bat or glove first. If the batsman is clean bowled, then any subsequent run would be a bye, adding a run to the team total but not the batsman's tally.